# C# Linq extension: for-loop not break- or continue-able

Tags: c#, linq

I recently implemented this *Linq*-extension for usage in automated tests. I know that I can just use a `for`-loop; however, also working in *iOS*, I like if you can read your method code almost like an English sentence when using them.

```
/// <summary>
/// Repeats an action x times
/// </summary>
/// <param name="times">The number of times an action should be repeated</param>
/// <param name="action">The action that should be repeated</param>
public static void DoIt(Int32 times, Action<Int32> action)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
        action(i);
}
```

This works very well and you can use it like this:

```
DoIt(5, i => {
    // Here goes the code that should be executed multiple times
});
```

It is clear to read as "Do it 5 times with current index i". However, now that I wanted to use this call also in my regular code, I noticed that I can not use `break;` or `continue;` inside the `DoIt`-Block.

Is there any possibility to escape the *Linq* expression using the existing language supported techniques?

Comment: You can `continue` by using `return`. You can't really `break` unless you throw an exception (nasty).

Comment: The only solution I can think of would be to return a bool and break according to it.

Comment: Also, `DoIt(5, i => Console.WriteLine(i))` doesn't look any more English than `for (int i=0; i<5, i++) Console.WriteLine(i);` to me..

Comment: Yes, I do not want to throw exceptions here. Return would work, but I can not continue the code that might come after the DoIt call.

Comment: You're probably better off just getting used to C# idiomatic code. It's a good skill to be able to switch between languages *and* their styles.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: you could return some value that is inspected by the loop and then acts accordingly.

Comment: @zneak: I was thinking about this as well, but then I would not use the language specific break; or continue;. Also with returning a boolean, I would only be able to handle one state, but there are at least two since break; and continue; are quite different.

Comment: @CommuSoft true. Looks nasty though. If I saw it in production, I'd replace it with a for-loop in a heart-beat.

Comment: @AlexanderFuchs booleans have two states - that's kind of their thing :P

Comment: As soon as you `return true` (continue) or `return false` (break), you will get continue/break type functionality.  A boolean is all you need.

Comment: @AlexanderFuchs, your lambda expression is a function in itself, not a loop body, and therefore you will not be able to use break or continue statements from it, regardless of what you do. Choose your poison.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: But wouldn't I lose then the capability to completely exit the loop? With a return; statement?

Comment: From what I have seen from this discussion - this IS more poison than helpful and I rather use a for-loop than some weird workarounds.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: you can use an enum to semantically rename the result, but I agree it is still a dirty hack

Comment: Side note: " implemented this Linq-extension" - code show in the post is not an extension method and does not look like any LINQ methods... Usage of `Action<T>` does not really qualify method to be called that way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: good point. Indeed it is lacking a `this` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

You could slightly modify the `Action<T>` into a `Predicate<T>`:

```
public static void DoIt(Int32 times, Predicate<Int32> action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
        if(action(i)) {
            break;
        }
}
```

Now you can use a `return` in your block. If you `return false;` it will emulate a `continue;`, if you use `return true;`, it will emulate a break:

```
DoIt(5, i => {
    if(i == 1) {
        return false;//here we continue
    } else if(i == 3) {
        return true;//we break after the third time
    }
    Console.WriteLine("We run for the "+i+"th time!");
    return false;
});
```

The downside is that the last line of your block **must always contain** a `return false;`. You could see it as the predicate asking "*Stop now?*".

So to summarize:

```
return true;  -> break
return false; -> continue
```

## Giving the child a name

The solution is not very clean I admit: first of all, it is a bit confusing to work with booleans. You can solve this problem however by introducing an `enum`:

```
public enum LoopResult : byte {
    Break = 1,
    Continue = 0,
    End = 0
}
```

The `End` is in fact an alias for `Continue`, but can be seen as a more "natural" way to express it, in that case one can rewrite the `DoIt` with a `Function<Int32,Result>`:

```
public static void DoIt(Int32 times, Function<Int32,LoopResult> action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
        if(action(i) == LoopResult.Break) {
            break;
        }
}
```

And rewrite it as:

```
DoIt(5, i => {
    if(i == 1) {
        return LoopResult.Continue;//here we continue
    } else if(i == 3) {
        return LoopResult.Break;//we break after the third time
    }
    Console.WriteLine("We run for the "+i+"th time!");
    return LoopResult.End;
});
```

## C#s lack of a preprocessor/precompiler

But furthermore it doesn't make good reading to place `return` parts into your code. Since C# has no (standard) *precompiler* I think there is however no way to automatically rewrite code such that one can use a `break` and `continue` expression. On the other hand a precompiler introduces an additional level of trouble and many programs can get ruined simply by starting to do a bit too much magic with precompilers.

Comment: Appreciate the effort for this, but in general this would things more complex than what was the intention of the extension method. If I can not use the language specific loop controlling calls, I might as well just stay away from the linq extension in cases I need some routing logic.

Comment: @AlexanderFuchs: I think that is indeed the best option. If C# had - like C++ - a precompiler, it was possible. But not having a precompiler was probably a good idea as well since it tends to make things way more complicated that what it is sometimes worth.

Answer (score 2):

This would work.  Return false to exit the loop prematurely.

```
public static void DoIt(Int32 times, Func<int, bool> action)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        if (!action(i))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoIt(5, i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        return i != 3;              // returning false exits the loop
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to make the `DoIt` method more powerful by modifying it in this way:

```
public static void DoIt<T>(
    T initial, Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T, T> iterate, Action<T> action)
{
    var t = initial;
    while (condition(t))
    {
        action(t);
        t = iterate(t);
    }
}
```

In this way `break` is handled in the `condition` predicate - return `false` and you will `break`. And `continue` is handled by calling `return` in the `iterate` function.

This allows your `DoIt` method to iterate on any type - including regular classes or even anonymous types.

You could do this:

```
DoIt("X", t => t.Length <= 3, t => t + "!", t => Console.WriteLine(t));
```

Or even this:

```
DoIt(
    new { counter = 0, sum = 0 },
    t => t.sum < 50,
    t => new { counter = t.counter + 1, sum = t.sum + t.counter },
    t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.counter);
        Console.WriteLine(t.sum);
    });
```

Comment: That is certainly a *more complete* re-invention of the for-loop. Still no break/continue though..

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Yes `break` and `continue` are there - the `Func<T, bool> condition` does the `break` and simply calling `return` in the `Func<T, T> iterate` function does the return.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I actually got this signature from the `Generate` method in Microsoft's Reactive Extensions - and then changed it a bit to suit what the OP was doing.

Comment: A problem is that sometimes the state - deciding whether to continue/break - is part of the `action`. In that case one needs to "copy" the state to `condition`. This can be hard if you modify a datastructure. So splitting this up can result in a harder problem.

Comment: @CommuSoft - Yes, I agree. On the positive side this approach does enforce a separation of concerns - almost an MVVM type of logic layering.